# Assigning a column to a SparseDataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, sparse-matrix, sparse-dataframe

Consider -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3]})
df

   a
0  1
1  2
2  3
```

I'd like to do two things:

1. Convert the dataframe to sparse with a default fill value of `False`
2. Assign a column of all False values to this sparse dataframe

Here's two seemingly similar approaches I've come up with.

First method; assign the column and convert the result to sparse.

```
df.assign(newcol=False).to_sparse(fill_value=False)

   a  newcol
0  1   False
1  2   False
2  3   False
```

Second method; *first* convert to sparse and *then* assign the column.

```
df.to_sparse(fill_value=False).assign(newcol=False)

   a  newcol
0  1     0.0
1  2     0.0
2  3     0.0
```

These `0.0`s threw me off.

FWIW, this similar-to-the-second method also seems to work properly, giving `False` instead of `0.0` -

```
df = df.to_sparse(fill_value=False)
df['newcol'] = pd.SparseSeries([False] * len(df), dtype='bool_', fill_value=False)
df

   a  newcol
0  1   False
1  2   False
2  3   False
```

I'm confused by why two seemingly similar methods produce radically different outputs. What's the correct way to do this, and why is there a difference between these outputs?

Comment: `.assign(newcol=[False] * len(df))` will assign new col with False. Maybe scalars are converted to similar datatype of existing sparse dataframe when assigned to it.

Comment: @coldspeed opened an issue https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/19163, it might be a bug

Comment: check jezz comfirmed its a bug. Check this out. It might be fixed in coming update of pandas. https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/19163#issuecomment-356570006

Comment: @Dark thanks... you can write an answer for now stating that it's a bug.

Comment: Related PR : https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/13849